# Fast way to compare row-wise matrix with vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `MxN` and two row vectors `B` and `D` of dimension `1xN`. I would like to know the fastest way to compare `B` with each row of `A`. All elements are `1` or `0`.

Specifically,

```
A=[  1     1     1;
     1     1     0;
     1     0     1;
     1     0     0;
     0     1     1;
     0     1     0;
     0     0     1;
     0     0     0];



  B=[1 1 1];
  D=[1 0 0]
```

I want to construct a matrix `C` of dimension `Mx1` with `C(i)=1` if

`B(1,1)>=A(i,1)` and `B(1,2)>=A(i,2)` and ... `B(1,N)>=A(i,N)` and

`D(1,1)<=A(i,1)` and `D(1,2)<=A(i,2)` and ... `D(1,N)<=A(i,N)` and

`B(:)` is different from `A(i,:)` and

`D(:)` is different from `A(i,:)`

In the example

```
C=[0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0];
```

One way to do this could be

```
lownew=repmat(D,size(A,1),1);

greatnew=repmat(B,size(A,1),1); 

C=(sum(lownew<=A,2)==N & sum(greatnew>=A,2)==N & sum(lownew==A,2)~=N & sum(greatnew==A,2)~=N);
```

Is there any faster way? My real matrix `A` has dimension greater than `10^6`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the fastest way (in number of code lines and computation time) is certainly to use `bsxfun`.

In your case:

```
tmp = bsxfun(@ge, A, B);
res = all(tmp,2);
```

is what you are searching for. Note that `bsxfun` automatically handles inputs of different sizes, like in your exemple, so there is no need to use `repmat` or matrix multiplication here.

**edit**

Same idea with the new constraints. Note that `a<=b` and `a~=b` simplifies in `a<b`:

```
tmp = bsxfun(@lt, A, B) && bsxfun(@lt, D, A);
res = all(tmp,2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have elaborated a bit more my question. Could you give a look?

Comment: Hey, don't change the question like that after an answer. Please ask another question instead. I'll edit my answer anyway.